# InDesign — Text Frame position within a table cell

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

Is there a way to set the position of the *Text Frame* within a table cell? I need some kind of anchor or margin for this.

The names of the official holidays should be at the same position in every cell of the calendar:

[image: one cell of the calendar]

The calendar is just a 39×12 table:

[image: calendar]

Each date is represented by one cell of the table with the day number, name of the day and a leader. I've added some holidays names above these leaders. Every name is a single Text Frame.

Project page (in German): http://georgmierau.de/calendar.html

Comment: You mention "text frame within a table cell". What part of your design is the table? From what I understand text frames cannot be anchored in a table cell,  you can however have text inside a table cell (the cell serving as the text frame). Can you include more of your design as reference?

Comment: Grayson, as you can see, the table is not a part of the calendar, it IS the calendar :) Btw. I think, I should try something like a new layer with an extra table for holidays names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two other ways that this could be solved.

**1. Baseline shift / Underline**

Keeping all the elements in one cell as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the 1 fr is normal text followed by a spacer (here I used N-space).

To create the space I applied a right indent tab after the N-space which will indent the text to the far right and everything you write after that indentation will flow from right to left (in this example the word Anything).

[image]

The leaders here are an underline applied to the Right Indent Tab and the text (Anything).

[image]

I also applied a Baseline shift and tweaked both the Baseline shift and the Underline Offset until I get the desired lockup.

[image]

**2. Using A text frame as an Anchor**

For this to work consistently and positioned exactly the same u need to use the Anchor Options and Customise its position.

[image]

[image]

If anyone needs further explanations on how I used the Custom Anchor Options to sit in the right place, please ask.

Hope all this is clear.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned before, I think the simplest solution would be to have the holidays on a separate layer. Trying to add them to your current table, although it is possible, could overcomplicate your design.

**That being said this could be achieved by splitting each day's cell into three parts (Instead of one):** Far left would be the date. Top right would be for holidays. Bottom right for leader characters.

Not so pretty example:

[image]

Comment: Splitting the cells is more complicated for me than adding a new layer. Already did it and the result looks really good. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I figured, wanted to solve it anyways haha